# Arc subtended by stretching of a conical spiral spring

Tags: springs, geometry

[image: Problem set up]

I'm trying to work out the angle subtended by the stretching of a conical spring and I have a solution but I'm not 100% sure about it so would appreciate some feedback.

An Archimedes spiral spring is shown above with radii at various points. What I would like to come up with is an equation for the angle that each part of the spring gets stretched by as a function of the radius and the distance from rest $x$. I know that for a normal spiral spring of constant radius $R_{ss}$ if it is stretched by a small amount $dx$ then it will subtend an angle $d\theta$ therefore
$$
dx=R_{ss}d\theta \\
\int_0^{x}dx=R_{ss}\int_0^\theta d\theta \\
\therefore \theta=\frac{x}{R_{ss}}
$$

For a spiral conical spring with radius $R_{cs}$ that starts at $R_{cs0}$ and grows to $R_{cs1}$ what I did was integrate the radius:
$$
dx=dR_{cs}d\theta \\
\int_0^{x}dx=\int_{R_{cs0}}^{R_{cs1}} \int_0^\theta d\theta dR_{cs} \\
\therefore \theta=\frac{x}{R_{cs1}-R_{cs0}}
$$
It seems too simple though hence why I would like to check here what the thought is on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, Its not right. If the cone becomes more, steep at the limit when $$   R_{cs1} \Longrightarrow R_{cs0} \quad \theta \Longrightarrow \infty $$

Comment: My apologies but I'm not sure I understand your answer. Since it's an Archimedean spiral the cone doesn't become more steep because the slope of the cone is constant.

Comment: @enea19 ok fine, but lets assume we started with a  more steep cone, it is going to have smaller theta, but by your calcs it will have a bigger one.

Comment: Aah, I see what you mean. But isn't that ok? I mean, a conical spiral spring that has less than a single turn is not very useful. Mathematically I understand the problem, but in practice it would never happen.